# nm-applet runs fine from the command line but not at startup

Tags: networkmanager, application, notifications

If I run nm-applet from the command line, it works fine, and an icon appears in my notification area.

But, I have `nm-applet` in my list of startup applications, and it fails to load when I log in.

How do I get it to start when I log in?

I'm using MATE in Linux Mint 16 Petra.

Comment: Which desktop environment you use, if any?

Comment: Some desktop environments (or at least some window managers, including openbox) have an startup file which is shell script. There you can start your applications like this: `(sleep 1 && nm-applet) &` instead of this: `nm-applet &` to have a small delay before application starts that X has time to start, so applications don't fail to start due to the lack of running X server.

Comment: @RistoSalminen: Sorry. I'm using MATE. I should have mentioned that before. I've updated my question. I'll try your suggestion and reboot a little later.

Comment: You don't actually have to reboot your whole computer to test that: just run `killall mdm` (I'm not sure if that process is named mdm, since I don't use Linux Mint, but you'd verify it by looking for `mdm` in the output of `ps axjf`).

Comment: @RistoSalminen: Unfortunately, using `(sleep 1 && nm-applet) &` did not solve the problem.

Comment: Please add more details on the way startup applications work. Don't assume you get an expert for *both* nm-applet and mate. Get the debugging output from the failed nm-applet instance.

Comment: look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/484856/46437), I only was able to provide a delay by having a script call the actual command, I think startup applications suffer some kind of "file must exist" validation.. You can also try "adding layers to the execution" like `bash -i -c "xterm -e 'nm-applet & sleep 10'"` (the ending sleep is just to prevent xterm close too fast) (`bash -i` makes it work differently and may help, remove `-i` if you want)